# Forcing sandbox attribute to specific value in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm using TinyMCE as an wyswyg editor, and I'm trying to make it always add a sandbox attribute to every iframe it finds, and resetting it to a specific value, for example "allow-scripts allow-same-origin".

I've tried by adding to valid_elements:

"iframe[name|src|srcdoc|seamless<seamless|width|height|sandbox:allow-scripts allow-same-origin]"

But it doesn't work; also

"iframe[name|src|srcdoc|seamless<seamless|width|height|sandbox:allow-scripts]"

does not seem to work; I've tried with

"iframe[name|src|srcdoc|seamless<seamless|width|height|sandbox:]"

which correctly adds the sandbox attribute if missing, but DOES NOT replace its value with the empty one if the attribute is already present, as I was expecting...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a [node filter](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.html/tinymce.html.domparser/#addnodefilter). The [setup function](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#setup) like this should do the job:

```
setup: function(editor) {
  editor.on('PreInit', function() {
    editor.parser.addNodeFilter('iframe', function(nodes) {
      nodes.forEach(function(node) {
        node.attr('sandbox', 'allow-scripts allow-same-origin');
      });
    });
  });
}
```

It will get each iframe during parsing and force the relevant sandbox attribute to be what you want.

P.S. using both `allow-scripts` and `allow-same-origin` attributes is [not a recommended practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) (see the note below the attribute descriptions).

Comment: Thanks! This might be perfect, I'll test it in a day or two and report back; by the way, using allow-script and allow-same-origin are not recommended IF THE INCLUDED PAGE HAS THE SAME ORIGIN... In this case, I'm using iframe to include youtube videos, so it is NOT from the same origin...

Comment: Tested the proposed solution and it's working perfectly.
Thanks!